# Maven how to invoke a plugin goal?

Tags: maven

In the Tomcat Maven plugin, tomcat7-maven-plugin, how to invoke the goal, tomcat7:deploy, after package phase ? can you please give me concise sample pom file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an execution for the plugin and tie it to a phase after the package phase, i.e. verify or install..

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>deploy</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```